# Combine 2 eloquent result and update them

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables that have relation each other :

1st table products migration :

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

2nd table discount migration :

```
Schema::create('discounts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('product_id');
    $table->double('rate', 8, 2); // rates between 0.05 ~ 0.2  
    $table->foreignId('period_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Product model :

```
/**
* Get the product associated with discount.
*/
public function discounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Discount::class);
}
```

Discount model :

```
/**
* Get the discount associated with product.
*/
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

What i've tried so far is a bit silly :

```
$productWithoutDiscount = Product::doesntHave('discounts')
->where([
    ['section', Session::get('section-budget')],
    ['status', 'PREPARED']
])->get();

$productWithDiscount = Product::with('discount')->whereHas('discounts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('rate' ,'>', 0.05);
})->get();

$productAll = $productWithoutDiscount->merge($productWithDiscount);
```

Above code works, however, i also need to update them, that wont happened as the merged eloqunet instance will be converted to collection (which doesn't have access to update() method)

How can i get both the product which don't have discount AND product which have discount with above 0.05 rate and update them ?

**Update 1**

So i follow @Salvon's advice to use union, so these my following code atm :

```
$productAll = Product::with('discount')->whereHas('discounts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('rate' ,'>', 0.05);
})->union(Product::doesntHave('discounts')
->where([
    ['section', Session::get('section-budget')],
    ['status', 'PREPARED']
]));
```

Then another problem came out, because when i execute the update method like so :

```
try {
    $productAll->update([
        'period_id' => Session::get('period');
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Data successfully updated.'
    ], 201);
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => $th->getMessage()
    ], 500);
}
```

nothing was updated and not even any error come out,
Already check the protected $fillable on my model and the 'period_id' is there.

how can I solved this ?

**Update 2**

Weird after i cahge the order of query like so :

```
$productAll = Product::doesntHave('discounts')->where([
    ['section', Session::get('section-budget')],
    ['status', 'PREPARED']
])->union(Product::with('discount')->whereHas('discounts', function ($query) {
    $query->where('rate' ,'>', 0.05);
}));
```

The update() method works. What is the cause ?

Comment: Use union instead

Comment: Will give it a  try, so there's no eloquent way ?

Comment: eloquent has union

Comment: You can also try subqueries, but I think that union is more readable

Comment: @Savlon i tried and solved my issues with union, thanks for the help !

Comment: @itepifanio yes, i think union is much more readable, thanks for the advice though

Comment: @Savlon i updated my question with another probelm, would you please help me, whats going on there ?

Comment: @owf have you checked your logs? What do they say? Have you checked what the return value of the update function is? What does it say? Problem solving is your friend here.

Comment: @Savlon nothing on logs, but it return success json response (201) with message "Data successfully updated". but nothing happened on the database. i updated the question for the details

Comment: The update function returns a Boolean as to whether it succeeded or not. What is that value?

Comment: @Savlon it returns 0 (false), but no error was cathced, if the result was false then it should be cathed right ?